# Vue Random Router Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

```html
{
    path: '/link_1',
    name: 'link_1',
    component: () => import('./views/Link1.vue')
},
```

It is possible to have it one path like /link_1 but every time when go to this route load different component.

Like: First time when go to /link_1 load Link1.vue and second time when user go to /link_1 load and display Link2.vue.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: I have <router-link to="/link_1">Link 1</router-link> I want every time when user click on link load diferent link or component. Route does not have to be the same. Eg. Click to Link 1 first time go to /link_1 second click /link_2.

Comment: <router-link to="/link_1" to="/link_2" to="/link_3">Link 1</router-link> Like this :)

Comment: Why not send a number as a variable/params in the URL

Comment: You think like /link_/:number ? But i want this :number be each click diferent.

Comment: So keep a counter and change the link based on that counter

Comment: I dont know hove do that. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `watch` and `<component>` to render a dynamic component each time the link is clicked.

For example, this generates 100 components named `component1` through `component100`, rendering one at random each time the `<router-link></router-link>` is clicked:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter)


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/random/:id'
  }]
})



const components = Array.from(Array(100), (x, i) => {
  return {
    name: `component${ i+ 1 }`,
    props: ['lorem'],
    template: `
    <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
    <v-avatar>
    <span class="blue-grey--text headline">${i + 1}</span>
    </v-avatar>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-card-text>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout justify-center>
        <v-flex>
        <span class="subheader" v-html="lorem"></span>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
    </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
    `
  }
}).reduce((carry, c) => {
  carry[c.name] = c
  return carry
}, {})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components,
  router,
  computed: {
    current() {
      return `component${this.cid}`
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cid: 1,
      lorem: 'What mystery does the next page hold?'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': {
      handler: function() {
        let id = this.cid

        while (this.cid === id) {
          id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
        }

        this.cid = id
        
        fetch('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&format=html').then(res => res.text()).then(data => {
          this.lorem = data
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.0.2/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-toolbar app>
        <v-toolbar-items>
          <v-btn :to="`/random/${cid}`" color="deep-orange darken-4" dark>Click Me</v-btn>
        </v-toolbar-items>
      </v-toolbar>
      <v-content>
        <v-slide-x-transition leave-absolute mode="out-in">
          <component :is="current" :lorem="lorem"></component>
        </v-slide-x-transition>
      </v-content>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```